# If $f(x)=\int_{-2}^x\left|x+1\right|dx$ then what can be said?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, continuity

> If $f(x)=\int_{-2}^x\left|x+1\right|dx$, then
>
> 1. $f(x)$ is continuous in $[-1, 1]$
> 2. $f(x)$ is differentiable in $(-1,1)$
> 3. $f'(x)$ is continuous in $[-1, 1]$
> 4. $f'(x)$ is differentiable in $(-1,1)$

I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

### Update:

Yes, I agree that the question is ambiguous. I will verify it tomorrow and post another update regarding the specific requirements.

Comment: You cannot have $x$ both as a limit and as a variable in $dx$. The one inside is $dt$? And is it $|x+1|$ or $|t+1|$?

Comment: Are you sure you want $\;x\;$ , the same letter for the function's variable as the integral's upper limit?

Comment: The first thing that can be said is that it's bad form to write $x$ as both the integrating value and the integrating bound.

Comment: @DonAntonio The question requires $x$ to be both the limit and the variable,

Comment: @ Astrobleme: $x$ to be both the limit and the variable makes no sense !

Comment: @Astrobleme I' afrad that either makes no sense or else makes some sense I am unaware of...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you mean

$f(x)=\int_{-2}^x\left|t+1\right|dt$

The function $g(t)=|t+1|$ is continuous, hence $f$ is differentiable on $[-1,1]$ and

$f'(x)=g(x)$

Your turn !

Answer (score 0):

You can split the integrand as follows:

Case $(1) $: When $x > -1$

$$\int_{-2}^x|p+1|dp$$
$$=\int_{-2}^{-1}|p+1|dp+\int_{-1}^x|p+1|dp$$
$$=-\int_{-2}^{-1}(p+1)dp+\int_{-1}^x(p+1)dp$$
$$=\frac {1}{2}+\frac {(x+1)^2}{2}$$
$$=\frac {x (x+2)+2}{2}$$

So, $$f (x)=\frac {x (x+2)+2}{2}$$ and 
$$f'(x)=x+1$$

Case $(2) $: When $x \le -1$

$$\int_{-2}^x|p+1|dp$$
$$=-\int_{-2}^{x}(p+1)dp$$
$$=\frac {1}{2}-\frac {(x+1)^2}{2}$$
$$=-\frac {x (x+2)}{2}$$

So, $$f (x)=-\frac {x (x+2)}{2}$$ and 
$$f'(x)=-x-1$$

Hope this helps you.